# Ubuntu 20.04 pre-installed firefox lagging on scroll in fullscreen mode

Tags: firefox, 20.04, fullscreen

When I go on any website (google.com, youtube.com or duckduckgo...) when the window is in fullscreen mode and I want to scroll, firefox starts lagging really hard. When I make the window just a little bit smaller, everything is running fluently.
I really don't know if that is a bug or anything known. I already searched for solutions but found nothing.

I don't have this problem with other browsers or applications.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have also found that disabling smooth scrolling in preferences solves the issue, even when fractional scaling is enabled.

Answer (score 6):

This error only occurs when fractional scaling is enabled. If you disable it everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

check in its preferences that « hardware video acceleration » is enabled, and
in about:config set « layers.acceleration.force-enabled » to true

sources :

https://discourse.ubuntubudgie.org/t/firefox-scroll-lag-on-ubuntu-budgie-19-04/1783/2

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but for people who are still looking for a solution, turned out for me Ubuntu decided to reset the refresh rate of my monitors to 60Hz rather than 144Hz. Reapplying the correct refresh rate solved all lag issues for me.

Weirdly enough, Firefox was really laggy, however the main menu and chrome for example were fairly smooth, making it seem like Firefox was the culprit rather than Ubuntu itself.

Answer (score -1):

I experienced scroll lag and choppy mouse movements (Ubuntu Mate 20.04, new install) even after the installation of a new NVIDIA 710 graphics card.  I thought I had installed the required NVIDIA graphics driver but double checked and found that the default "nouveau" driver was installed!  The NVIDIA 470 driver was installed from "Additional Drivers" in the main menu; system rebooted and all is well. Problem solved.  Lesson?  Check the simple stuff first.  Install the correct graphics driver for your system's GPU.

Comment: Not really applicable here considering all the previous answers.